# Creating this text file in the right format with delimiter on hadoop

Tags: hadoop, input, hive, csv

Hey guys right now I'm trying to create a input text file for hive on hadoop, but I'm confused by the commmand since I'm just a beginner.

The command is this:

```
hive> create table employee(emp_id int,name string,salary double) row format delimited fields terminated by ',';
```

So what should be my text file be, what does delimited mean?

Is something like this okay?

```
1244, Daniel, 200000
1344, John,   59999
8742, Smith, 98009
```

Is my format right?

Comment: Well, did it work? You shouldn't have spaces in your data. Otherwise, lookup delimited in a dictionary

Comment: Why do you need to install Hive? If you're interested in learning Hadoop at all, download the Hortonworks or Cloudera virtual machines that are pre built

Comment: I don't know what you're confused about. What errors are you currently experiencing when you run that query? You've not loaded the file yet, as far as I know

Comment: You should please try to insert the data before asking the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're making a standard CSV file. A file consisting of Comma Separated (or **delimited**) Values.

And it looks fine, but you'll want to remove extra spacing around the commas unless you'd like to keep them in the database table.

Then, you'll also need learn the `LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH` syntax or to use `EXTERNAL` tables over a path `LOCATION`

Comment: I don't think I need to write it. What you're provided is fine. When I say extra spacing, I mean exactly that. Do you want `Daniel` in the database, or `"   Daniel    "`? Note: it matters more for the integer values because they cannot have any spaces

Comment: You've already accepted my answer. If you have additional problems, feel free to create additional posts.

Answer (score 0):

To understand Hive, you have to understand what it does exactly. Hive is a component within the Hadoop ecosystem that creates metadata around physically stored data (which are in most cases files) to be able to query this data. This metadata is then stored in a relational database. Hive also provides a SQL engine.

When there is a query on Hive data, the application looks up the metadata  (Where are the files located, what structure do they have, etc). and the corresponding jobs are executed to retrieve the data.

So with a Hive CREATE TABLE command you basically defines this metadata.

You define factors such as:

- Structure (JSON, CSV, custom...).
- Location within the distributed file system (HDFS)
- Partition (Subdirectories)
- Delimiters
- Format (Textformat, column based special format)
- Compression ratio

With your specific Hive Create Table command you tell Hive to create an entry in the metastore about csv files that are separated with a comma. As you not specified any location, it will be located under the default location (if you have not changed the standard settings this would be apps/hive/warehouse/employee on HDFS. Your sample would meet the structure you defined.